# Concatenate a list of numbers into a list with .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, list, replace, nodes, innerhtml

I've got a list of items and I need to create a function that puts a number front of each item in the list. So "pine nuts", would become "2. pine nuts"

Here's the list I'm passing in (with the parameter ulPassed) -

```
    <li id="one" class="hot"><em>fresh</em> figs</li>
    <li id="two" class="hot">pine nuts</li>
    <li id="three" class="hot">honey</li>
    <li id="four" class="cold">balsamic vinegar</li>
    <li id="five" class="cold">yoghurt coated banana chips</li>
```

Here's my code so far -

```
function swapInnerHTML(ulPassed){

ulPassed = ulPassed.innerHTML;

var grocList = document.getElementById('groceries');
var listItems = grocList.getElementsByTagName('li');

var listNumber = 1;

var count = 0;
for (count = 0; count < ulPassed.length; count++) {
    var thisItem = listItems[count].getAttribute('class');      //pointing towards each class item
    var foodText = thisItem.firstChild.nodeValue;   //pointing towards the child node of each item
    foodText = foodText.replace(foodText, listNumber+". "+foodText); //replace the text
    thisItem.firstChild.nodeValue = foodText; //update the text
    listNumber++; //next list number
}

console.log(ulPassed);
return ulPassed;
```

}

So I'm attempting a for loop to cycle through the list, and replace each of the food items with itself but with a list number in front of them, also a ". ". In that same loop I'm increasing the list number. The problem I'm having is getting it to replace the text itself, I feel as if I'm pretty close, but I don't feel as if I'm using the firstChild.nodeValue correctly.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using Javascript you could use an ordered list `<ol>` instead of a unordered list `<ul>` especially if this is done only for a visual purpose. Also, [counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) in CSS can be easily styled, e.g.

```css
ul {
  counter-reset: food 0;
}

li::before {
  counter-increment: food;
  content: counter(food) ". "; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li class="hot"><em>fresh</em> figs</li>
   <li class="hot">pine nuts</li>
   <li class="hot">honey</li>
   <li class="cold">balsamic vinegar</li>
   <li class="cold">yoghurt coated banana chips</li>
</ul>
```

---

Otherwise in Javascript you could loop over all the list-items and set their `innerHTML` property using the index inside the `map` function

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('li')].map((food, i) => 
    food.innerHTML = [++i, food.innerHTML].join('. ')  
);
```

```html
<ul>
   <li class="hot"><em>fresh</em> figs</li>
   <li class="hot">pine nuts</li>
   <li class="hot">honey</li>
   <li class="cold">balsamic vinegar</li>
   <li class="cold">yoghurt coated banana chips</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion with the use of the map is great, my suggestion is for the more beginners:

```
const list = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
let arrLi = [].slice.call(list);

for (const [i, v] of arrLi.entries()) {
  v.innerHTML = `${i+1} ${v.innerHTML}` 
}
```